# Java socket inpustream stuck

Tags: java, sockets

I have problem with reading from socket inputStream. But only in one method in class. Here is my code:
server:

```
private void copyFile(String mainPath, String path) {
    outS.println("Sending file!");
    outS.println(path);
    outS.flush();

    BufferedInputStream fis = null;
    OutputStream os;

    File file = new File(mainPath);
    String str;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    long numOfChunks = file.length() / 4096, num = 0, lng;
    try {
        fis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        os = socket.getOutputStream();
        outS.println(numOfChunks);
        fis.read(buffer, 0, 4096);
        os.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
        os.flush();
        num++;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("<ERROR> Clerk, copyFile: File not found.");
        System.out.println(ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("<ERROR> Clerk, copyFile: Could not write or read file.");
        System.out.println(ex);
    } finally {
        try {
            fis.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Clerk.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    waitEnd();
}
```

client:

```
private void copyFile(String destination) {
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    long numOfChunks, num = 0;
    SBuffer sBuffer;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    InputStream is;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(destination));
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        is = socket.getInputStream();
        numOfChunks = Long.parseLong(inS.readLine());
        System.out.println(num + "/" + numOfChunks);
        int bytesRead = is.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
        bos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        num++;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("<ERROR> Client, copyFile: File not found.");
        System.out.println(ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("<ERROR> Client, copyFile: Could not write or read file.");
        System.out.println(ex);
    } finally {
        try {
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    outS.println("end");
    outS.flush();
}
```

Let me explain few things. Everythings goes fine, but client on line `int bytesRead = is.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)` will stuck, because nothing is in stream (is.available = 0 ). And i don't know why. Although i send it from server many times.

And I can't close stream, because socket will close too.

Method waitEnd() waits for string "end" in socket's input stream.

I have searched many tutorials and things on internet, but no one help.

Code which establish connection:

Server:

```
public void run() {
    try {
        ssocket = new ServerSocket(2332);
        Socket socket = ssocket.accept();
        clerk = new Clerk(socket, mainPath);
        (new Thread(clerk)).start();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    }
    try {
        ssocket.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    }
}


public Clerk(Socket socket, String path) {
    this.socket = socket;
    mainTree = new FileTree(path);
}

public Client(String address, String[] dirs) {
    try {
        socket = new Socket(address, 2332);
    } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    }
}
```

Client and clerk has same method run:

```
    @Override
public void run() {
    try {
        inS = new BufferedReader(iss);
        outS = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        iss = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    }
    msg();
    try {
        inS.close();
        iss.close();
        outS.close();
        ois.close();
        oos.close();
        socket.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code that establishes the connection?

Comment: I can, but it will be little longer. But in this case is not a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. I created second socket for file transfer only.